# Получение информации в том же месте где произошел запрос

Tags: java, netty

Я использую библиотеку нетти.

```
    ProxyOnlinePacket onlinePacket = new ProxyOnlinePacket();
    Proxy.getInstance().sendPacket(onlinePacket);//Отправляю пакет

    System.out.print("online: " + onlinePacket.getOnline());//Тут я уже должен получить онлайн полученный с сервера.
```

Пакет на стороне сервера.

```
public class ProxyOnlinePacket implements Packet {
private int online;

public ProxyOnlinePacket() {}

public ProxyOnlinePacket(int online) {
    this.online = online;
}

@Override
public void writePacketData(PacketBuffer buf) {
    buf.writeIntLE(ConnectionState.getPacket_ID(this));
    buf.writeIntLE(this.online);
}

@Override
public void readPacketData(PacketBuffer buf) {
    online = buf.readIntLE();
}

@Override
public void processPacket(Channel channel) {
    online = 5;
    channel.writeAndFlush(this);
}

public int getOnline() {
    return online;
}
```

}

Когда сервер получает такой пакет. Я отправляю тот же самый пакет с измененной переменной online.

На стороне клиента

```
public class ProxyOnlinePacket implements Packet {
private int online;

public ProxyOnlinePacket() {}

public ProxyOnlinePacket(int online) {
    this.online = online;
}

@Override
public void writePacketData(PacketBuffer buf) {
    buf.writeIntLE(ConnectionState.getPacket_ID(this));
    buf.writeIntLE(this.online);
}

@Override
public void readPacketData(PacketBuffer buf) {
    online = buf.readIntLE();
}

@Override
public void processPacket(Channel channel) {
    System.out.print("Пакет пришел обратно! " + getOnline());
}

public int getOnline() {
    return online;
}
```

}

Мне нужно каким то образом получить онлайн в том месте где я создал сам обьект пакета и отправил его же.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно создать метку того, что пакет пришел:

```
public boolean processed = false;

@Override
public void processPacket(Channel channel) {
    System.out.print("Пакет пришел обратно! " + getOnline());
    processed = true;
}
```

И проверять ее состояние, например циклом:

```
ProxyOnlinePacket onlinePacket = new ProxyOnlinePacket();
Proxy.getInstance().sendPacket(onlinePacket);//Отправляю пакет

for(;!onlinePacket.processed;);//Цикл идет, пока метка не изменится, а значит, пока не прилет ответ
onlinePacket.processed = false;//Возвращаем стандартное значение
System.out.print("online: " + onlinePacket.getOnline());//Этот код обработается, когда пакет получит данные об онлайне
```

Comment: На вид выглядит не очень.

Comment: Принципиально отличающихся вариантов просто не существует.